# How to have colors in the output of SQL result

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer can I get the result of a SQL query in color?

For example:

```sql
Select * from Employee;
```

If `EmployeeID = 100` I want the name column to be displayed in green color.  If `EmployeeID = 200` I want the name column to be displayed in red color.

All other fields (gender, salary) should be in normal colors.

The reason I am asking for this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_A
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table_B;
```

For this query, I want o/p to be in color for the columns where it is different from table A.

Requirement may see a bit strange. But I just want to know if this can be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQLDeveloper, we use Java swing which allows for some minimal rendering of html.  In the grids, this can be done if the value of the cell starts with `<html>`. This means you could use a case/decode statement to prefix the html tag and a font to change the color of the cells when they are printed.

```
select 
  case empno 
  when 7839 then '<html><font size="5" color="red">'||empno 
  when 7698 then '<html><font size="5" color="green">'||empno 
  else empno||''
  end empnpo,
ENAME ,
JOB ,
MGR ,
HIREDATE ,
SAL ,
COMM ,
DEPTNO  from emp
```

[image]

Comment: To complete this excellent answer, if you prefer having the background set please use `bgcolor` and use the hex code to have more options.
`when 7698 then '<html><font size="5" bgcolor="#98FB98">'||empno `

Answer (score 2):

You can use user defined reports as per [this blog post by Vadim Tropashko](http://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/search-code-in-sql-developer-3-0/)

On the other hand, you can highlight values in the results grid using the standard Edit/Find dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CASE 
WHEN EMPLOYEEID = 100 THEN 'GREEN'
WHEN EMPLOYEEID = 200 THEN 'RED'
END EMPLOYEEID
```

should be put after select but before from